# callback communication between a kotlin class and Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, oop, android-activity, interface

Communication between two android components like Activity and fragments could be done by viewmodel or interfaces .
But How do we communicate between a Kotlin class and an Activity and Vice Versa.

My requirement

I have a Kotlin class interface :

```
interface classA {
...
    fun getdata()
...

}
```

and its implementation

```
    @Singleton
    class classAImpl @Inject constructor(
        private val dataStoreManager: DataStoreManager
    ) : classA {

        override fun getData(){
        }
    }
```

This implementation opens an activity ActivityA

```
    class classAImpl @Inject constructor(
        private val dataStoreManager: DataStoreManager
    ) : classA {

        override fun getData(){}

        fun openActivity(){
           val i = Intent(this , ActivityA::class.java)
           startActivity(i)
        }
    }
```

I have a dialog listener interface which is a callback of another dialog .

```
    interface DialogListener{
        fun onDialogDismiss() {}
    }
```

The ActivityA implements this interface , which gets the dialog callback.

```
    class ActivityA : AppCompatActivity , DialogListener{

        override fun onDialogDismiss(){
           //do something
        }
    
    }
```

This is the entire structure.
My requirement : Whenever the dialogListener callback reached the ActivityA , I need to make the same callback to classAImpl . Which I tried and cannot be done by implementing dialogListener in classAImpl.

Is there any other way to communicate back to the classAImpl from the activity ?

[image]

Comment: Based on the diagram, Activity manages the Dialog, so the appropriate way to handle this is have Activity call the ClassImplA function from within Acitivity's `onDialogDismiss()` function. ClassImplA doesn't need to know anything about the dilaog.

Comment: @Tenfour04 so basically create an instance of ClassImplA in the activity right ? Meaning I have to create another method in the ClassA Interface . This was the first solution that came into my mind. But if I create that method in the interface ,  that method would be exposed to everyone who create the instance of ClassA. I dont want that. Plus the activity is being created from ClassImplA so isn't it weird that I have to again create an instance of ClassA inside the activity. Not sure just asking.

Comment: I think I read this too quickly. I see the issue now. When you start an Activity, there's no way to get a reference to its instance. Usually we start Activities from other Activities if we are expecting a result from them, and for that we use `startActivityForResult()` or the newer ActivityResultContract. The first activity never actually has a reference to the second activity, and vice versa. I guess the question is, where did ClassAImpl come from? If it was instantiated from some Activity, I suppose ClassAImpl needs to call back to its own Activity to use features like ActivityResultContract

Comment: @Tenfour04 That is exactly the problem , and ClassAImpl is created from an activity or a fragment component. but how would we use startActivityForResult() for the same . It can only be used inside an Activity class right.